# C Pthread is a condition or a barrier more efficient to pause a thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a thread that I want to pause most of the time. I could use a barrier or a condition variable. Is there a performance difference?

Comment: "I want to eat a steak. Which one is better, a table cloth or a chair"? You might want to explain what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a performance difference?

There is a *semantics* difference.  Although both condition variables and a barriers can cause a thread to block until appropriate action is taken by one or more other threads, the details of the "appropriate action" are significantly different.  You should use whichever is more natural for your application.

If you want to investigate relative performance, then write alternative implementations and *test them*.  There is no substitute.  I would be inclined to guess that the more natural will win on account of the need to write more code to adapt the other to your requirements, but that's speculative.